# Can someone help me return a value?

Tags: php

I have created a loop which returns a random number between two values. Cool.

But now I want the script to return the following value too: The number of unique numbers between two similar numbers.

Example:
4
5
8
22
45
3
85
44
4
55
15
23

As you see there is a double which is the four and there are 7 numbers inbetween. So I would like the script to echo these numbers two so in this case it should echo 7 but if there are more doubles in the list it should echo all the numbers between certain doubles.

This is what I have:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    $min=0;
    $max=50;
    echo rand($min,$max);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Can someone help me or guide me? I'm learning :)

Thanks!

Comment: Right now you are just outputting each random number, so you will need to start by _remembering_ them … for example by putting them into an array. And then on each new random number you produce, you go check whether it is contained in that array already. Your calculation of “numbers between” could then probably be something like the difference between the index where you found that number in the array and the current number of elements.

Comment: Put the rand into an array `$list = array();` and `$list[] = rand($min,$max);` then process the array with two for loops.

Comment: With your given example, what exactly do you want to happen if after that last 23, the next random number would be a 4 again? Is it supposed to output 3 then (55 15 23 are between the new 4 and the previously last one)? Then you might need to search said array from the end.

Comment: For instance the numbers which are randomly generated are:
2-22-32-15-55-49-31-2-5-77-82-32-32

The output should be:
7-9-1

7 because number 2 was doubled after 7the number
9 because number 32 was double after 9th number
1 because number 32 was doubled after 1ste number

Did I explain it clear now?

Answer (score 2):

So You need to seperate script for three parts:

1. getting randoms and save them to array (name it 'result'),
2. analyze them,
3. print (echo) results

Simply - instead of printing every step of loop, save them to array(), exit loop, analyze every item with other, example:

1. take i element of list
2. check is i+j element is the same
3. if is it the same - save j-i to second array() (name it 'ranges')

And after this, print two arrays (named by me as 'result' and 'ranges')

**UPDATE:**
Here's solution, hope You enjoy:

```
$result = array(); #variable is set as array object
$ranges = array(); #same

# 1st part - collecting random numbers
for ($x = 0; $x < 20; $x++) 
{ 
  $min=0; 
  $max=50; 
  $result[] = rand($min,$max); #here's putting random number to array
}
$result_size = count($result); #variable which is containg size of $result array

# 2nd part - getting ranges between values
for ($i = 0; $i < $result_size; $i++)
{
  for ($j = 0; $j < $result_size; $j++)
    {
      if($i == $j) continue; # we don't want to compare numbers with itself,so miss it and continue
      else if($result[$i] == $result[$j])
            {
              $range = $i - $j; # get range beetwen numbers
              if($range > 0 ) # this is for miss double results like 14 and -14 for same comparing
                            {        
                              $ranges[$result[$i]] = $range;
                            }
            }
    }  
}

#3rd part - priting results
echo("RANDOM NUMBERS:<br>");
foreach($result as $number)
{
  echo ("$number ");
}
echo("<br><br>RANGES BETWEEN SAME VALUES:<br>");
foreach($ranges as $number => $range)
{
  echo ("For numbers: $number range is: $range<br>");
}
```

Here's sample of echo ($x is set as 20):

```
RANDOM NUMBERS:
6 40 6 29 43 32 17 44 48 21 40 2 33 47 42 3 22 26 39 46 

RANGES BETWEEN SAME VALUES:
For numbers: 6 range is: 2
For numbers: 40 range is: 9
```

Comment: Let me give this a try. Be right back with my findings :). Thanks

Comment: To get more beautiful (printed) results, You can use array's with key => value construct, here's link ;) good luck
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Oke. I'm here now:

for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    $min=0;
    $max=50;
    $result = rand($min,$max);

    echo "$result<br>";

}

Comment: I'm simply not getting anywhere. Is there someone who can guide me?

Comment: Thanks my friend. Your amazing. But there is one small thing. It should only mention the gap number so if we have the list 2 - 5 - 7 - 9 - 19 - 5 - 66 - 32 - 54 the gapnumber is between the 5's which is 3 ( and these numbers should be lined up below eachother :)

Can you help me with this last and you'll simply be the greatest. And when your in the neightbourhood come have a cup of coffee ;)

Comment: That's simple, beacause in situation now is for part of Your example (5-7-9-19-5) is also counting the number '5', so for this You need add '-1', here's that function:
$ranges[$result[$i]] = $range; -- correct one will be: $ranges[$result[$i]] = $range - 1;

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fish:

Put the rand into an array $list = array(); and $list[] = rand($min,$max); then process the array with two for loops.

```
$min=0;
$max=50;
$list = array();
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; ++$x) {
    $list[] = rand($min,$max);
}

print "<pre>";print_r($list);print "</pre>";

$ranges = array();
$count = count($list);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $a = $list[$i];
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < $count; ++$j) {
        $b = $list[$j];
        if($a == $b) {
            $ranges[] = $j-$i;
        }
    }
}

print "<pre>";print_r($ranges);print "</pre>";
```

Comment: I think something goes wrong here. Let me explain what I want to accomplish with this script.

1. I want it to generate numbers between two values.
2. I want it to output numbers between repeaters
3. I want to analyze these gaps between repeaters 
&
4. Compare these to results I enter inside the database to find out if there are similarities in trends.

I now get arrays which don't give me the gap value's.

It's difficult for me.

Comment: I'm still not finished. Can someone else help me please?